# XAMPP Apache and MySQL not working after reinstall

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I downloaded XAMPP and it was working fine, but I realized that I had downloaded to the wrong directory. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it in the right place and now it's not working. I'm not sure what I did wrong. Is it a port issue? I have Apache on port 80 and SSL port 443; MySQL is on port 3306.

I am getting this error.

```
23:16:23  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
23:16:23  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
23:16:23  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
23:16:23  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
23:16:23  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
23:16:23  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
23:16:23  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer?

Answer (score 0):

1. I had this problem;
2. so i had to install **easyphp, wamp, xamp** on my window but it was
   the same The **mysql: 3306** port is probably used by another
   application port solve this problem..
3. By suggestion, I installed **UwAmp 3.1.0** . who has corrected the
   error now I can access the database

[image]